# The mgf and cf of Student's t distribution

Tags: t-distribution, moment-generating-function, characteristic-function

A student's t distributed rv $X$ has characteristic function but no moment generating function. I wonder if cf(X)=$E[e^{itX}]$, why we cannot take $t=-iu$ to get the mgf $E[e^{uX}]$? (This question may be very silly...)

If we cannot know mgf of $X$, is there some accurate numerical way to evaluate $E[e^{X}]$, i.e., the value of the mgf at $u=1$?

Comment: Although $E[e^{uX}]$ certainly does not exist for real $u$, it easily exists when $u=it$ is purely imaginary.  The (simple) reason is that $|e^{itX}|=1$ and so the size of the integral is bounded by $1$ times the total probability (also equal to $1$).

Answer (score 2):

**"... why we cannot take $t=−iu$... "**

Because, according to the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Definition) of the characteristic function, $t$ must be a real number.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. This paper discussion something similar but not the same I guess. Indeed, I just want to calculate the $E[e^{X}]$ where $X$ is a student's t rv. I know that the mgf does not exist, but may be there is some numerical method to approximate, or this integral does not converge at all?

Comment: The mgf does not exist **for every** real $u$, and you're trying to approximate its value at $u=1$. Doesn't make sense, right? What are you trying to use this expectation for?

Comment: \@Zen. Yes, I am just curious. You see, $E[e^{X}]$ does not exist, but how about if we times X with, let's say, 0.05, or some factor "small", For example, let's generate a $Y$, which contains 1e6 $t$-distributed random numbers with df=4, and take $X=Y*0.05$ then $E[e^{X}]$ exist, which is around 1.002471 by simulation. I dont understand this indeed...

Comment: Isn't the simulation deluding you? Run `mean(rcauchy(10000))` several times in `R` and see the results. Multiplication by some small constant will not fix the problem.

Comment: But how to explain this then? (Let's just take df>2, so that we have some basic moments). I first thought the simulation may not stable, I mean, if I run it again, the mean(exp(0.05*rt(1e6,df=4))) will change, but the result is almost the same. I am really lost... Moreover, some other "small" factors can also make this like 0.2. Is there a link between the m and the "samll" factor? I really want to know more on this, are there some references studied this question?